# android action bar sherlock show action text and icon in split view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Need to create button with text in bottom action bar in "split" mode.

Here is code from Sherlock examples:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Save")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_compose)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Refresh")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

And that how it action bar looks in landscape orientation for Galaxy S3 resolution (as you see "search" item displayed with text and icon):

[image]

Now, rotate to portrait, action items goes down, and "Search" text invisible, but there is obviously more than enough space for it:

[image]

Please advice, how can I force Sherlock to show text if there is enough space?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. I googled it for a while and it seems that this is a ICS bug...  [Issue 30180](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30180)